# Ruby How to convert a flat array to hash

Tags: ruby, hash

I have the following Hash.

```
@facet_counts = {"facet_queries"=>{}, 
 "facet_fields"=>
      {"product_collection_value"=>["traditional and imitation", 304, "chunky", 34, "modern", 15, "coloured gems", 12, "traditional", 0, "traditional & imitation", 0],
       "product_material_value"=>["alloy", 161, "metal alloy", 132, "metal", 60, "925 sterling silver", 8, "lac", 3, "beads", 2, "beaded", 0, "brass", 0, "copper", 0, "crystal", 0, "fabric", 0, "feather", 0, "glass", 0, "jute", 0, "leather", 0, "pashmina", 0, "plastic", 0, "polymer beads", 0, "pu leather", 0, "rexin", 0, "rubber", 0, "satin", 0, "shell", 0, "silk", 0, "silk brocade", 0, "silver", 0, "silver alloy", 0, "stainless steel", 0, "sterling silver", 0, "stone", 0, "velvet", 0, "viscose", 0, "wood", 0, "wooden", 0, "wool", 0],
       "product_type_value"=>["jhumkis", 364, "danglers", 53, "drops", 7, "hoops", 6, "victorian", 2, "armlets", 0, "bands", 0, "bangles", 0, "beaded", 0, "beads", 0, "bib", 0, "chains", 0, "charms", 0, "choker", 0, "clip on", 0, "cluster", 0, "cluster pendant necklaces", 0, "clusters", 0, "cocktail", 0, "contemporary", 0, "cuff", 0, "cz", 0, "diamond look", 0, "double chain", 0, "double fold", 0, "double strand", 0, "earrings", 0, "fashion", 0, "gemstone", 0, "hasli", 0, "hath phool", 0, "kada", 0, "kamarband", 0, "kundan", 0, "link", 0, "links", 0, "maang tika set", 0, "mangalsutras", 0, "modern", 0, "oxidised", 0, "oxidized", 0, "pair", 0, "pearl", 0, "pendant", 0, "pendant necklaces", 0, "potli", 0, "pouch", 0, "rani haar", 0, "rings", 0, "saree pins", 0, "set", 0, "single chain", 0, "single fold", 0, "single stone", 0, "single strand", 0, "singles", 0, "sling bag", 0, "strings", 0, "studded", 0, "studs", 0, "thewa", 0, "tote bag", 0, "traditional", 0, "with chain", 0, "with gemstone", 0, "without chain", 0, "without gemstone", 0], 
       "product_plating_value"=>["yellow gold plating", 135, "gold plating", 98, "silver", 39, "black silver", 15, "rhodium", 2, "white rhodium", 1, "14k yellow gold", 0, "18k yellow gold", 0, "alloy", 0, "black gold", 0, "black rhodium", 0, "brass", 0, "cubic zirconia", 0, "oxidised", 0, "pearl", 0, "rose gold", 0, "rose gold plating", 0, "silver plating", 0, "sterling silver", 0, "yellow gold", 0, "yellow rhodium", 0],
       "product_gemstones_value"=>["cubic zirconia", 132, "pearl", 45, "semi-precious", 19, "crystal", 3, "precious", 3, "amethyst", 2, "citrine", 2, "garnet", 2, "peridot", 2, "green onyx", 1, "imitation kundan", 1, "iolite", 1, "aquamarine", 0, "black onyx", 0, "blue topaz", 0, "carnelian", 0, "chalcedony", 0, "coral", 0, "diamond", 0, "emerald", 0, "gem stones", 0, "green stone", 0, "howlite", 0, "hydro", 0, "jade", 0, "jasper", 0, "kundan", 0, "labradorite", 0, "lapis", 0, "lemon quartz", 0, "lemon stone", 0, "malachite", 0, "marcasite", 0, "moonstone", 0, "onyx", 0, "opal", 0, "pink amethyst", 0, "prehnite", 0, "quartz", 0, "rainbow", 0, "red onyx", 0, "red stone", 0, "red tiger eye", 0, "rhodolite", 0, "rose quartz", 0, "ruby", 0, "sapphire", 0, "smoky quartz", 0, "spinel", 0, "tanzanite", 0, "tiger eye", 0, "topaz", 0, "tourmaline", 0, "turquoise", 0, "white rainbow", 0, "white rainbow stone", 0],
       "product_occasion_value"=>["special occasions or gifts", 358, "wedding or festive wear", 245, "everyday wear", 119, "work wear", 4, "religious", 0]
  },
 "facet_dates"=>{}, 
 "facet_ranges"=>{}}
```

**What I want** The hash corresponds search results on a page. The array against each filed name indicates the values and the number of results having that value. But Since this is an array I am not able to access the counts easily.

What I am currently doing is:

```
    facet_fields=["product_collection_value","product_material_value","product_type_value","product_plating_value","product_gemstones_value","product_occasion_value"]
    @count_hash = Hash.new
    facet_fields.each {|field|
        print @facet_counts["facet_fields"][field]
        @facet_counts["facet_fields"][field].each_with_index{ |v,i|
            if i%2 == 1
                next
            else
                @count_hash[@facet_counts["facet_fields"][field][i]] = @facet_counts["facet_fields"][field][i+1]
            end
        }

        print "\n\n"
    }
```

**Issue** : This creates a new Hash. But the problem is that in case of multiple entries of same tag. Eg. `Modern` is in `product_collection_value` and `product_type_value` so the value get overwritten. IS there a way by which I can convert the original hash so that the counts can be accessed easily?

Comment: It is not clear what you are trying to do. Posting your code does not help. Rather than doing that, explain what you want.

Comment: @sawa: Thanks for the suggestion. I have updated the question accordingly. Kindly review

Comment: Here are some tips for writing questions: 1. Provide input data. (You've done that.) 2. Reduce the number of elements in the input to the minimum needed for the question. 3. Shorten text strings, symbol names, etc. ("cv" instead of "product collection value"). 4. Format to avoid the need for horizontal scrolling. 5. Provide the desired output corresponding to the input. (Often the question can be understood from this alone.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the answer is:
`Hash[@facet_counts["facet_fields"].map { |k, v| [k, Hash[*v]] }]`

Answer (score 1):

I believe what you are trying to do it this:

```
@count_hash = @facet_counts['facet_fields'].map do |k, v| 
  Hash[*v] 
end.inject({}) do |s, i| 
  s.merge(i) { |_, old, new| old + new }
end
```

The first part maps each facet field to a hash of key-value pairs, for example - the first has will look like this:

```
{"traditional and imitation"=>304, 
 "chunky"=>34, "modern"=>15, "coloured gems"=>12, 
 "traditional"=>0, "traditional & imitation"=>0}
```

The second part merges them by summing identical keys. The result of your example will look something like this:

```
{"traditional and imitation"=>304, "chunky"=>34, "modern"=>15, 
 "coloured gems"=>12, "traditional"=>0, "traditional & imitation"=>0, 
 "alloy"=>161, "metal alloy"=>132, "metal"=>60, "925 sterling silver"=>8, 
 "lac"=>3, "beads"=>2, "beaded"=>0, "brass"=>0, "copper"=>0, "crystal"=>3, 
 "fabric"=>0, "feather"=>0, "glass"=>0, "jute"=>0, "leather"=>0, "pashmina"=>0,
 "plastic"=>0, "polymer beads"=>0, "pu leather"=>0, "rexin"=>0, "rubber"=>0, 
 "satin"=>0, "shell"=>0, "silk"=>0, "silk brocade"=>0, "silver"=>39, 
 "silver alloy"=>0, "stainless steel"=>0, "sterling silver"=>0, ... }
```